# PC-Lint error : Error 307: Can't open indirect file 'gcc-include-path.lnt'

Tags: c, gcc, lint, pc-lint

I am trying to use PC-Lint on windows for exercising static code analysis on C files. I installed the software and ran the configuration setup for **gcc compiler** where I got the following files in the config directory:

```
co-gcc.h, co-gcc.lnt, env-ecl-console.lnt, filea.cpp, fileb.cpp, LIN.BAT,
lset.bat, options.lnt, std.lnt, std_a.lnt
```

However when I try to run the test sample by typing `>lin filea fileb` from the config directory, I get the following error:

```
co-gcc.lnt  37  Error 307: Can't open indirect file 'gcc-include-path.lnt'
```

How do we get the gcc-include-path.lnt file?

Comment: Email support@gimpel.com to get support for the product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error got solved by creating **lint_cmac.h, lint_cppmac.h, gcc-include-path.lnt, and size-options.lnt** files using the makefile **co-gcc.mak** located in **PC-lint9.00h\lnt** folder.